# How do I accept Indian Language text in Django Template and store that in GAE Datastore

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I have defined model like this.

```
class Item(db.Model):
  itemName = db.StringProperty()
  localName = db.TextProperty()

class ItemForm(...ModelForm):
  class Meta(object):
     model = models.Item
     exclude=[]
```

I want to input, store and view 'itemName' in English and 'localName' in an Indian Language say 'Kannada'.

Kindly guide me on this.

Comment: what happened when you tried to do that?

Comment: I do not know the django settings required for this and other pre-requisites to achieve this.

Comment: no, what was the error you received when you attempted to save such data? In other words, what have you tried?